# Server Root and MapPath()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a file structure set up like this:

```
ServerRoot
    applicationRoot
        filePage.aspx
    files
        chart.png
```

My application page called filePage.aspx uses another app to custom build charts.  I need them saved in files folder.  This is how our client's production server is set up and I cannot change this.

I do a `_page.Server.MapPath("/files")` but it gives me a `InvalidOperationException` and states Failed to map the path '/files'.

**UPDATE:**

So it has to be set up this way MapPath("/").  My local asp.net server can't handle the MapPath that way, but our IIS development box has no problem with it and it works fine.  Interesting.
How do I get it to save to files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's a security violation to go outside the directory structure of the virtual directory in asp.net 2.0 and up. You'll need to make a virtual directory to the directory and use that.

Comment: +1 alternatively, have the `AspEnableParentPaths` property set to true in IIS, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524697%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
Server.MapPath("~/files")
```

The ~ represents the root of the web application so the folder returned will be correct no matter which subdirectory you are in.

Comment: You are correct about the ~, but that doesn't match his structure.  The files directory is outside the root of his application.

Answer (score 0):

`_page.Server.MapPath()` will attempt to map from the root of the application (NOT the root of the server).

Try `_page.Server.MapPath("../files")`.

**EDIT**

You may run into security issues when trying to map outside of your application root.  If that is the case, you can do something like this:

```
Server.MapPath("~").Substring(0, Server.MapPath("~").IndexOf(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~").Replace("/", "\"))) + "\files"
```

This looks rather complex, but essentially says "map my application, then remove the application root from the end and add '\files' instead".

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
_page.Server.MapPath("files")
```

Comment: I believe that will look for the files directory inside of his application (but it is outside the application root).

Comment: This still gives me a physical path of C:\applicationRoot\files\"